# Next.js Hot Reload Mac OS Intel/M1

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm fighting since couple of days, that with next.js the app with the build-in feature [fast refresh](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh) is not working on Mac OS with M1 processor with intel processor everything works fine.

Using next.js latest version.

`npx create-next-app@latest --typescript`

Install simple example next.js + typescript.
Node Version 16.3.2 - npm version 8.1.2

I tried with different node versions via nvm.

Is there anyway to see some logs? I don't get any errors with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

After the posting of my issue. I found the solution.

I updated to the latest yarn version.
`npm install --global yarn`

Didn't know that this is connected.